# How to theme a view that displays content from a relationship?

Tags: theming, views

I have a page for `Organization`. Each organization has a `Featured Person` field which is an unlimited node reference to the `Person` content type. The organization can have many featured people. I also need to be able to customize the markup for each view-row and therein lies my problem.

I set up the view according to [another question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25678/23862). The view is able to select and display the correct `Person` data only when **Show: Content**. AFAIK, this does not let me customize the markup for each row because the rendered markup is sent directly to the template.

If I change to **Show: Fields** in order to get more control over the theming, the view will display the fields related to the *organization*, not the *people* (since I am on an organization page, and the contextual filter is set to the organization id, I suppose).

How do I set up my view so I can display the relationship content (Featured People) and still customize the template for each row or people?

Answer (score 0):

With **Show: Field**, each individual field can be toggled to any of the relationships in the view. It is similar to **Show: Content** and **Show: Rendered Entity** except the dropdown list is buried one step further down.

Switch to **Show: Field**, and edit each field and set the dropdown list to the Featured Person relationship. Then, go about your theming just as you would with any other fields template.

[image]

Comment: I spent the better part of two days trying to figure this out and *of course* I find the answer 30 minutes after I post the question :\